# With MySQL, how do you store the current time as UTC time?

Tags: mysql, datetime

When I insert data into my MySQL database, a lot of the time I need to store the current datetime. I always want to store my datetimes as UTC time.

How do I store the current UTC time? Is there a built-in function or do I have to apply an offset to NOW()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` which can provide all kinds of Date and Time Values and specific to your request you can use `UTC_TIMESTAMP`, `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` which returns the current UTC date and time as a value in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` or `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP() + 0;
        -> '2003-08-14 18:08:04', 20030814180804.000000
```

More Info is described here about MySQL Date/Time Functions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `timezone` property in your `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld_safe]
timezone = UTC
```